# delete empty lines

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, tr

I could need some help with a oneline script im building. The script should give me a list of services, which are running on the current system. I wanted to realize this with systemctl.

The current oneliner looks like this:

```
systemctl list-units --type service | grep -f /etc/update-motd.d/service.list
```

However this command always creates a blank line between the services which are listed

```
  smbd.service                       loaded active running Samba SMB Daemon    

  uuidd.service                      loaded active running Daemon for generating UUIDs  

  virtlogd.service                   loaded active running Virtual machine log manager 

  zabbix-agent.service               loaded active running Zabbix Agent
```

I would like to remove the empty spaces. After some google research ive found some solutions with tr (like 'tr -d ""' or 'tr -s ""'), but this doesnt seem to work. Ive even tried some solutions with grep or sed but none of them helped me wih this.

edit: following solutions I tried without success:
| grep "." 
| sed '/^$/d
| grep "\S"

Some help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: you probably have a empty line in ...service.list file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:
`systemctl list-units --type service | grep -f /etc/update-motd.d/service.list | grep -v ^$` This should remove any emtpy lines

Comment: This also didnt work... seems like the systemctl command opens the output in a "less" like output, not a stdout. Seems like this causes the empty lines, which i cant delete. 

Any idea, how to get the output to stdout?

Comment: Works on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. What is the content of this `service.list` file?

Comment: just some entries like:

smbd.service

uuidd.service

Comment: Well.... now it works... just reconnected via ssh and tried something  and worked and now your example works to... maybe a brokenpipe thingy in the ssh connection!? im just kinda cnfused right now....

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr` to squeeze newlines:

```
$ systemctl list-units --type service | \
  grep -f <(tr < /etc/update-motd.d/service.list -s \\n)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing are not empty lines - they're long trailing sequences of space characters that appear to be part of the `systemctl` tabular output:

```
$ systemctl list-units --type service | grep bluetooth | xxd
00000000: 626c 7565 746f 6f74 682e 7365 7276 6963  bluetooth.servic
00000010: 6520 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  e               
00000020: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000030: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
00000050: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 6c6f 6164 6564            loaded
00000060: 2061 6374 6976 6520 7275 6e6e 696e 6720   active running 
00000070: 426c 7565 746f 6f74 6820 7365 7276 6963  Bluetooth servic
00000080: 6520 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  e               
00000090: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
000000b0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 200a                    .
```

They appear as empty lines because of wrapping by the terminal.

You *can* remove them with `tr`, for example by squeezing horizontal whitespace:

```
$ systemctl list-units --type service |  tr -s '[:blank:]' | grep -f service.list 
bluetooth.service loaded active running Bluetooth service 
cron.service loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon 
polkit.service loaded active running Authorization Manager
```

Another option, which preserves the tabular format better, would be to remove only trailing spaces:

```
$ systemctl list-units --type service | sed 's/ *$//' | grep -f service.list 
bluetooth.service                                                                         loaded active running Bluetooth service
cron.service                                                                              loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon
polkit.service                                                                            loaded active running Authorization Manager
```

There *should* be a way to stop `systemctl` from trying to format the output (or at least to be responsive to the `COLUMNS` environment variable), but I can't find it.